# EF linq query working in linqpad but not in the App

Tags: linq

I have creatred a query in linqpad and it works but when i try to use it in my blazor app  the app throws an error.

I have three tables, tblOpportunity, tblOppStatus and lkpStatus

and an opportunity can have many status's depending on how mature the enquiry is.  So i need to get all the latestest status for each opportunity.  I also want to be able to filter the dataset so i get only opportunities with staus of x, y and z

```
void Main()
{
    var output=from o in TblOpportunities
                 join sub in (
                 //get the latest status ID for the from the joining table
                 from smax in TblOppStatuses
                 group smax by smax.OpportunityID
                 into g
                 select new
                 {
                     OName = g.Key,
                     MaxS = (from t2 in g select t2.OppStatusID).Max()
                 })
                 on o.OpportunityID equals sub.OName

                 join st in TblOppStatuses on sub.MaxS equals st.OppStatusID
                 
                 //get the statu sname form the lookup table
                 join lst in Lkp_Statuses on st.StatusID equals lst.StatusID
                 
                 join c in TblClients on o.ClientID equals c.ClientID
                 
                 select new
                 {
                     c.ClientName,
                     o.OpportunityName,
                     sub.MaxS,
                     lst.Status,
                     lst.StatusID
                 };
    
    int[] filter = { -1, 62};
                 output.Where(of=>filter.Contains(of.StatusID))
                 .Dump();
                 
}
```

The error that comes in the subquery

```
MaxS = (from t2 in g select t2.OppStatusID).Max()
```

if i comment this out the query runs but doesn't give me what i want.  Can anyone advise what i am doing wrong  As I say it works fine in Linqpad.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the error message?

Comment: Brandon, thanks for asking, I changed the query to this and it worked.       

                      group SMAX by SMAX.OpportunityID into g
                             select new  {
                                 OID = g.Key, 

                                 MaxS = g.Max(tc=>tc.OppStatusID)
                                 //(from t2 in grp select t2.OppStatusID).Max()

                             })

Comment: I'll close this